# How to fail static_assert on function use

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want compiler to complain when I try to print instances of one class,
let's say `T2`. In VS2013+ I can use:

```
template <typename T = float>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const T2 & t2) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Fail in << for T2");
    return os;
}
```

however, that does not work in VS2012 (`error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template`). Any ideas how to achieve this in VS2012?

Comment: seems that error does not mention static_assert but default template arguments typename T = float

Comment: well yeah but that's the problem; without the `template <...>` it just flat out fails to compile with the assert failing, since the function is instantiationed right away and the `static_assert` fails :/

Comment: Before MSVC 2017, templates are basically broken in those compilers. Starting with 2017, it's better: it is only non-compliant.

Comment: I now _do_ understand your question and I'd like to warn you. Even if you could make MSVC to accept that code, it will be completely ignored when you write for instance `std::cout << "not integral lol"`: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/527742/5470596

Comment: Well I have working overload that is getting called. So that part is working. Now I just want to fail the compilation **if** it's called. That part I cannot get to work under VS2012. Tbh I'm not sure how that linked questions is relevant here :/

Comment: If you want it so that you can't cout class T2 then why are you checking if T is a float?

Comment: because if you have `static_assert(false, ...` even inside template (or in this case function overload), it fails right away. going the long way around it with something that resolves to false (in this case basically `std::is_integral<float>::value`, which is always false) postpones the check to actual function instantiations

Comment: @rustyx would love to, but porting our 7.5M+ LoC project to newer VS is not really planned right now... too many dependencies :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2012 has incomplete support of C++11. Default template arguments for function templates, being a C++11 feature, is supported [starting with VS2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Maybe you can try this, but it is also using some C++11 features:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream & os, T const& t2) ->
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, T2>::value, std::ostream&>::type  
{
    static_assert(false, "Fail in << for T2");
    return os;
}
```

If that also doesn't work, I would just degrade gracefully for archaic crap like VS2012 and be done with it.

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1800
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, T2 const& t2); // will fail at link time
#else
. . .
#endif
```

Comment: the link time error is workable. I would love some custom error message in the build log, but still, this is better than nothing, thanks :) if no one comes with smarter way will accept this

Comment: That's what the SFINAE part is for. Have you tried it?

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't read it properly, I noticed it now and trying it out, seems like working, probably? :) Very clever, didn't think if this

Answer (score 0):

> "I want compiler to complain when I try to print instances of one
>   class, let's say T2"

```
#include <iostream>

struct T1 { int a; };
struct T2 { int a; };

template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const T & t2) 
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T2, T>::value, "Fail in << for T2");
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    std::cout << t1; // Works
    std::cout << t2; // Static assert fail
}
```

I'm not understanding. Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: Problem is that this adds "catch-all" output operator. When I later add `T3` it will just turn `std::cout << T3();` into no-op (`... { return os; }` to be precise). Which is not ideal...